# How to replace title for images

Tags: php, replace

Please, can anyone please tell me how to replace file title images.I'm trying to figure out how to replace the title portion of an image

```
$rem = array('-','_','%','+','img','photo','photos','picture','pictures','image','images','jpg','jpeg','png','bmp','copy');
$title = str_replace($rem,' ',$title);
$title = preg_replace("@\\b[a-z0-9]\\b ?@i", "", $title);
```

result

```
2015_ferrari_f430_18_1600.jpg -- > 2015-ferrari-f430-18-1600.jpg
Wimmer-RS-Ferrari-F430-Scuderia-1.jpg --> wimmer-rs-ferrari-f430-scuderia.jpg
3-Ferrari-F430-Stradale-Spy_1035.jpg -- > ferrari-f430-stradale-spy-1035.jpg
Auto-Veloce-Ferrari-F430-SVR-3.jpg --> auto-veloce-ferrari-f430-svr.jpg
Auto-Veloce-Ferrari-F430-SVR-8-1024x692.jpg --> auto-veloce-ferrari-f430-svr-1024x692.jpg

how to can be it..
2015-ferrari-f430.jpg
wimmer-rs-ferrari-f430-scuderia.jpg
ferrari-f430-stradale-spy.jpg
auto-veloce-ferrari-f430-svr.jpg
auto-veloce-ferrari-f430-svr.jpg
```

Comment: I don't really understand the criteria for removal. Do you want to get rid of the last portion of a file name, without extension, that has dashes, numbers, or an x?

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex pattern.

```
$title = preg_replace("/[_\-\d]+.jpg$/", ".jpg", $title);
```

But this won't work for all your strings since you don't have a standard pattern of replacement (for e.g. it won't work for `2015-ferrari-f430_18_1600.jpg` and `Auto-Veloce-Ferrari-F430-SVR-8-1024x692.jpg`).

Considering you want to replace any last numbers after a dash (including `x` in `1024x768`) you can also try this:

```
$title = preg_replace("/(?:-|_)[_x\-\d]+.jpg$/", ".jpg", $title);
```

Comment: I had tried earlier 
$title = preg_replace("[_\-\d]+.jpg$", ".jpg", $title); or
$title = preg_replace("(?:-|_)[_x\-\d]+.jpg$", ".jpg", $title);


but I got the message
Warning: preg_replace () [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '[' in D:\data\autoblogcar\wp-content\themes\project\inc\replaceimage.php on line 398

Comment: @aguswibowo can you check now. Updated the answer.

Comment: after I try the result is the same with 




$title = str_replace($rem,' ',$title);
$title = preg_replace("@\\b[a-z0-9]\\b ?@i", "", $title);




2015_ferrari_f430_07_1600.jpg --> 2015-ferrari-f430-07-1600.jpg
2015_ferrari_f430_18_1600.jpg --> 2015-ferrari-f430-18-1600.jpg
FERRARI-F430-ferrari-27721006-1024-587.jpg --> ferrari-f430-ferrari-27721006-1024-587.jpg